# first mysql insert query, then select query compare with 5000 records in one loop - increase speed of query

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing, php-5.3

I've one script for parsing xml feed data by user wise and that is also based on different websites.

Currently 1000 users resides into my database, and 10 sites also.

when i'm go for get rss feed into different sites that time first loop of all users and inside the users loop one another loop is reside and that is for different websites.

I'm also get all the data from all users by any site but when i'm insert that all data into my db it's also check for duplicate entries then it take very long time for that.

So please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give some details about your tables' design. In particular, please let us know the columns, their data types, and the indexes you have defined. Only a few of us are clairvoyant. :-) :-)

Comment: Hello, Following is my table structure please let it check and help me sir